# Behavior of postfix and prefix operators (Java)

Tags: java

Suppose I have `a+++b`. The compiler computes `(a++)+b` and not `a+(++b)`. Why?

Comment: Unary operators have higher [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Postfix Operator has more [precedence](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/CSE8A/Java_Operator_Precedence_Table.pdf) over prefix operator.

> the advantage of having a simple and well-memorizeable precedence list
>   in which all postfix operators come before any of the prefix operators
>   is sufficient to tolerate the minor drawback of always having to use
>   parentheses to compose pre- and postfix operators ++/--, as this
>   composition is used very seldom.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, `++a` is not prefix operator in Java, it's `unary`. And it has less [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than postfix operator (`a++`).

At general, compiler will execute operators with higher precedence first. So, first postfix operator (in your case `a++` is executed first, and additive operator `+` second.